# Objective C protocol circular dependency?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface, protocols

I have a protocolA in its own header file, that serves as an interface.
Then I have two concrete classes that are different implementations of that protocol.

Now, in my ViewController, I use this for declaring a property of type id , and it allows me to swap implementations without VC knowing anything about this.

I also have protocolB, that serves for delegate calls from those two implementation objects to the VC.

The problem is I have circular dependency.

In protocol A, i need to declare a "delegate" property of type id.
In protocol B, the delegate methods are sending reference to the caller which is an object of type id...

Is there a better design?

---

UPDATE with example, maybe it will be helpful for others.

**ProtocolA header:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 /*!
 Abstract interface for any Provider 
 */

@protocol DataProviderDatasource <NSObject>

@required
@property (nonatomic) id <DataProviderDelegate> delegate; 
-(void)update;

@end
```

**ProtocolB header**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DataProviderDatasource.h"
/*!
 Protocol that each  Data Provider implements to make delegate calls to notify its     delegate about data management operations.
 */

@protocol DataProviderDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)dataProviderWillUpdate:(id<DataProviderDatasource>)dataProvider;
-(void)dataProviderdidUpdate:(id<DataProviderDatasource>)dataProvider;
```

@end

Comment: could you post some code to make the context clearer?

Comment: Sorry but I am legally bound not to post any code.

Comment: Just some example code would be good.  i.e. call the classes MyCustomViewController and the protocol MyCustomProtocol etc...  Then we can see where the problems are occurring.

Comment: I added example code... But I did not add that forward declaration that is the solution to the problem, so that people would see what's the problem ;-)

Comment: @EarlGrey I am a bit late here, but you meant to know that there is a problem in class `DataProviderDatasource` you posted, right? Because I don't think the class is aware of `DataProviderDelegate`. Can you clarify your intention?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

like classes, you can forward declare protocols:

```
@protocol MONProtocolB; // << forward declaration -- #import not required

@protocol MONProtocolA
- (void)setDensity:(NSValue<MONProtocolB>*)pValue;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ << compiler recognizes this as an
                                           objc protocol
@end
```

then the compiler won't barf when it sees the protocol name and circular dependence is broken (unless your protocols both derive from another which is of course silly).

you can then `#import` MONProtocolB wherever there is physical dependence.